# Duplicate classes when building in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

i am getting an error when building an Android Studio project.

> Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

here is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.6.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 202
    versionName "2.0.0"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", "false"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

flavorDimensions "type", "name"

productFlavors {
    magazines {
        dimension "type"
    }
    magazine {
        dimension "name"
        // Remove next line to enable Crashlytics and change false to true in second line
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", "false"
    }
    wind {
        dimension "name"
        // Remove next line to enable Crashlytics and change false to true in second line
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", "false"
    }
    script {
        //// Use custom gradle file if it exists in script product flavor folder
        if (new File("./main/src/script/custom.gradle").exists()) {
            println 'custom.gradle script exists'
            apply from: "../main/src/script/custom.gradle";
        } else {
            throw new GradleException('No custom.gradle script exists')
        }
        //applicationId scriptApplicationId
        dimension "name"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", "true"
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
//added here
implementation fileTree(include: '*.java', dir: 'libs')
implementation fileTree(include: '*.so', dir: 'libs')
//til here
implementation project(':appiraterAndroid')
implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.26@aar'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.1'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i am sure that there is something to do with dependencies and versions , but i can't find out.

i tried to clean gradle cache and restarting Android studio , but i am still getting the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate project to androidx support

Click -> Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX

and update the libraries

Comment: faced the same issue "program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz" and solved the same when updated.

Comment: Shouldn't updating your libraries be enough? I don't see how migrating to AndroidX would help. If that really was the solution, then literally every app would be broken which doesn't make sense.

Comment: He may try to update the libraries without updating to androidx. Kindly have a try on this